# Encriptar en python como en Bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, debian

Tengo hecho un script eh mi maquina virtual de debian y quiero traducirlo a python para poder ejecutarlo en windows.

En bash uso el comando:

```
variable=$(openssl passwd -crypt -salt "salto" "contraseña")
```

de modo que me devuelve la contraseña encriptada con el salto proporcionado. Estoy buscando el modo de hacer lo mismo pero en python. Es possible o estoy perdiendo el tiempo?

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay una implementación "pura" (en python sólo) de la biblioteca completa openssl. Aunque hay utilidades para invocar openssl desde python (como [openssl-python](https://pypi.org/project/openssl-python/)), dependen de que tengas instalado openssl, así que no son muy útiles para tus objetivos (pues si consigues instalar openssl en windows, podrías usarlo directamente desde scripts `.bat`).

No obstante, si tan solo lo necesitas para cifrar contraseñas con sal (que no salto), no necesitas instalar openssl, pues la biblioteca estándar python trae el módulo [`crypt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html) precisamente para eso.

Mira:

```
>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt("12345678", salt="salto")
'saX6EvfO393Go'
```

Y compara con lo que produce openssl:

```
$ openssl passwd -crypt -salt "salto" "12345678"
saX6EvfO393Go
```

### Actualización

El módulo `crypt` está implementado sólo en Unix, por lo que no sirve para las necesidades del usuario.

Existen implementaciones en python "puro" de la funcionalidad específica necesaria para el hash de una clave. Estas implementaciones pueden instalarse en Windows mediante `pip`. Una de ellas es `passlib`, que podríamos usar en la forma siguiente:

```
>>> import passlib.hash
>>> passlib.hash.des_crypt.encrypt("12345678", salt="sa")
'saX6EvfO393Go'
```

Esta librería fuerza a que el valor de `salt` tenga solo dos caracteres, pero no es problema ya que de todas formas la función `passwd -crypt` de openssl sólo considera los dos primeros caracteres del `salt`, de todas formas. Vemos que sale lo mismo.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda! Lo desconocia.

Por lo que he estado viendo lo que dices es correcto, pero no se puede ejecutar en windows. La libreria crypt esta hecha solo para Unix

Comment: @mileswiles Tienes razón! He actualizado la respuesta con otra posibilidad, mira a ver si te sirve

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error:

`AttributeError: module 'passlib' has no attribute 'hash'`

En principio lo tengo todo instalado y todo correcto, no se si es problema de la libreria o que he hecho algo mal

Comment: @mileswiles Tienes razón, tenía una errata en la respuesta. La he corregido. El import debe de ser de `passlib.hash` y no de `passlib`  como tenía antes.

Comment: genial! ya funciona, muchisimas gracias! me has ayudado muchisimo